# Why is the viewfinder info display missing on my Nikon D90?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90

My Nikon D90 is not giving any Viewfinder Info Display across the bottom. How do I turn it back on?

Answer (score 1):

You could first try resetting the settings of the camera by doing the following:
Press the two buttons with the green dots by them, AF Mode and Exposure Compensation button. Hold them together at the same time for a few seconds. This is also in the manual.

If that fails, it is likely an issue that you have to send the camera to a Nikon repair facility for. This seems to be a somewhat common issue that others have had. Nikon ended up repairing faulty wiring it seems. See:

- http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2559444#forum-post-31476144
- http://www.digitalphotographer.com.ph/forum/showthread.php?40387-Nikon-D90-viewfinder-problem
- https://secure.flickr.com/groups/nikon_d90/discuss/72157623471099339/